# Pass mother class instance and choose the right override with child class parameters

Tags: c#, oop, polymorphism, overloading

If i have a `IRecord` interface, with `RecordA` and `RecordB` classes that implements it.
If another class `Foo` has the following methods :

```
public void DoStuff(RecordA param){};
public void DoStuff(RecordB param){};
```

Why can't i call :

```
public void CallingMethod(IList<IRecord> recordList)
{
   foreach(var item in recordList)
      DoStuff(item); 
}
```

Comment: Because your methods take specific types which implement the interface, but which may have other properties and methods that the interface does not have. You would have to create a `DoStuff()` method that takes an `IRecord` parameter.

Comment: That's precisely my goal, i would like to do different instructions depending on the IRecord implementation i'm using because they don't all have the same properties and methods. And i can't have a method `DoStuff` in `IRecord` because it would require datas `IRecord` shouldn't know.

Comment: @Ythio, can you elaborate on "data IRecord shouldn't know"?  IRecord doesn't need to know it - only the specific implementations need to know it because it's not (I assume) passed in as a parameter.

Comment: @Ythio With your current implementation you are making classes tightly coupled. You would need to create another `DoStuff` method if a new class `RecordC` is introduced implementing `IRecord` interface. You might want to re-think your design if you have specific logic to execute based on the type of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do it would be to modify your `CallingMethod` to test the type of each item and cast it to that type before calling `DoStuff`:

```
public static void CallingMethod(IList<IRecord> recordList)
{
    foreach (var item in recordList)
    {
        if (item is RecordA)
        {
            DoStuff((RecordA)item);
        }
        elseif (item is RecordB)
        {
            DoStuff((RecordB)item);
        }
    }
}
```

---

In use, you might have the interface and classes defined as:

```
interface IRecord
{
    List<string> Tracks { get; set; }
}

class RecordA : IRecord
{
    public List<string> Tracks { get; set; }
    public int Speed { get; set; }
}
class RecordB : IRecord
{
    public List<string> Tracks { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

And then your methods would do something with the unique properties of the two classes:

```
public static void DoStuff(RecordA param)
{
    param.Speed = 78;
}

public static void DoStuff(RecordB param)
{
    param.Size = 12;
}
```

Now, we can create instances of the two classes, add them to a list of their common interface type, and pass that list to `CallingMethod`:

```
static void Main()
{
    var ra = new RecordA { Speed = 5 };
    var rb = new RecordB { Size = 10 };

    var recordList = new List<IRecord> { ra, rb };

    Console.WriteLine($"record A Speed before: {ra.Speed}");
    Console.WriteLine($"record B Size before: {rb.Size}");

    CallingMethod(recordList);

    Console.WriteLine($"record A Speed after: {ra.Speed}");
    Console.WriteLine($"record B Size after: {rb.Size}");

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

And we can see that the output did indeed change the unique properties of the classes:

[image]

Comment: But in the future, if i add a RecordC and RecordD and RecordE, i'll have to modify the method each time, and the iff will become quite big.

Comment: That's correct. This is just alternative to the better answer by @OutstandingBill, (his answer is the way I would actually do it). With his idea, when you implement a new `RecordC`, you also implement the `DoStuff` that goes along with it.

Answer (score 2):

Define `DoStuff` in the interface and implement in `RecordA` and `RecordB`.  Then for each item in the list, call the method on the item.

**To illustrate the encapsulation part**

```
interface IRecord
{
    void DoStuff();
}

public class RecordA : IRecord
{
    public int Foo;

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        Foo++;
    }
}

public class RecordB : IRecord
{
    public string Bar;

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        Bar += "again ";
    }
}

public void CallingMethod(IList<IRecord> recordList)
{
    foreach(var item in recordList)
    {
        item.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

Note that neither the interface nor the calling code know about the public (or private) members of IRecord implementations apart from DoStuff.

Comment: In my business logic, IRecords implementations are holding datas for later use (export, display, easy processing, etc...). In my DoStuff, i use datas like another server URL, the RootFolder of the current Web, etc... I think this should be unknown for IRecords and its implementations.

Comment: IRecord does not need to know about the data encapsulated within instances of the implementations.  The instances have already been created when you run through the list, and so already have the data in their members.

Comment: I think i may have a vocabulary problem in my previous comment. When i said i don't want IRecord to know about RootFolder of the current Web for example, i meant i don't want IRecord to hold in its member this information, nor have it passed in a method, because i have the probably stupid feeling that manipulating this kind of data isn't the right role for IRecords and its implementations. Their role is to hold query records for easier manipulation (you couldn't have know that last part, i didn't tell it). I don't know if i explain it correctly, it's more a problem of the role each class have.

Comment: All `IRecord` has to do is declare a method called `void DoStuff();`. It doesn't need to know anything about how the concrete classes implement it. Then the concrete class `RecordA` will implement it's own version of `DoStuff()`, as will `RecordB`, `RecordC`, etc. But the fact that `DoStuff()` is declared in the interface means that you can do: `foreach(var item in recordList) item.DoStuff();`

Answer (score 0):

This pattern may helps

```
public interface IRecord 
{
}

public class RecordA : IRecord
{    
}

public class RecordB : IRecord
{
}

public class RecordCollection<T> : List<IRecord>  where T : IRecord
{
    public RecordCollection(List<T> records)
    {
    }
}
```

Then having

```
 public static void CallingMethod(IList<IRecord> recordList)
 {

 }
```

You can call it this way:

```
CallingMethod(new RecordCollection<RecordA>(new List<RecordA>()));
CallingMethod(new RecordCollection<RecordB>(new List<RecordB>()));
```

Comment: How do the `DoStuff(RecordA)` and `DoStuff(RecordB)` methods fit in here?